# Aspectj using @annotation not working

Tags: java

I want to make pointcut work with annotations,but this pointcut not working.

This is where my annotation using:

```
@RequiresPermissions(value = {"user:view"})
public static String users(Request request,
                                   Response response){
}
```

RequiresPermissions.java:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequiresPermissions {
    String[] value();

    Logical logical() default Logical.AND;
}
```

AdminPermissionsAspect.java:

```
@Aspect
public class AdminPermissionsAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    void annotatedMethod() {}


    @Before("annotatedMethod() && @annotation(requiresPermissions)")
    public void execute(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequiresPermissions requiresPermissions) throws Throwable {

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    //        Method method = signature.getMethod();
    //        RequiresPermissions requiresPermissions = method.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class);
    }
}
```

This is my build message:

```
Information:2017-8-31 0031 22:33 - Compilation completed successfully with 1 warning in 5s 187ms
Warning:ajc: advice defined in om.puyixiaowo.fblog.aop.AdminPermissionsAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

I don't know why it does'n work,I tried only use 'execution(public * *(..))' without '@annotation(requiresPermissions)',it working.

Guys help me!